# Roots within unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $P(z)=\sum_0^nA_iz^k$  where $A_i \sim \mathbb U(0,1)$ is a random polynomial.Is it possible to find the probability or the estimates of the probability that no  roots are within the disc $|z| \leq 1?$By looking for the condition of Enstrom kakeya theorem when the coefficients are iid random variables ,we can see that the  coefficients will be ordered with a probability of $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ .So roots will lie outside with a probability of at least $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ for an nth degree polynomial. Obviously ,this is not much helpful  as n becomes larger and larger ,becuase then the coclusion is that all the roots are outside the disc with a probability that is at least anumber that approaches zero.How could we go about improving the estimates of this probability

Comment: Did you try the cases $n=1,2,3$? See what you can do there first

Comment: i will post my attempt as an answer as it will be too long for a comment

Answer (score 1):

Here is my  approach  and attempt  so far.First, we recall by Enstrom Kakeya theorem if $A_n \geq A_1..\geq A_0, $ then P(z) has no roots within the disc $|z| <1.$Now for iid coefficients the probability for this to happen is $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$.Hence all the roots lie outside the unit disc with a probility that is at least $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$As already pointed out this is not much help when n i very large.

 Now we try another approach.If \xi is the modulus of the root with minimum modulus ,then we have by Vieta's formula,
$$ \xi^n \leq \left|(-1)^{n-1}\frac{A_0}{A_n}  \right|=\frac{A_0}{A_n}.$$
Or,$\xi \leq (\frac{A_0}{A_n})^{1/n}$ 
Let $Y=(\frac{A_0}{A_n})^{1/n}$ be  a random variable  where $A_0,A_n$ are iid and distributed as $\mathbb U(0,1).$The distribution of $Y$ can be shown to be $$(F_W(w))^{n}$$ where W is the rv corresponding to the ratio of two uniform rv's in the interval (0,1). Now consider $\xi<Y<y.$ From this if we can show $$ P(\xi<y) \geq P(Y<y).$$

I want to show that $ P(\xi>1)$ approaches $0$ as  $n$ becomes large.Can that be done .Kindly correct me if my approach is wrong or mistaken or useless to achieve the goal of the problem